# awful sound after I close the music player

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card

I just installed win7 on a Toshiba Satellite P200-1FC and the problem that I'm facing with is that I get a very disturbing noise after I close the media player. It is a very loud, abnormal and annoying sound. First I was thinking that I don't have the right driver but ofter some help from a very kind SU user, I find the right drivers but the problem didn't get solved.

Do you have any idea about how can I fix my problem . I get the awful sound each time a close a music/media player or a voice conversation.

Comment: Which media player software are you using?

Comment: I get the same results no matter what player I'm using: VLC, Windows Media Player or even Yahoo Messenger voice call setup

Comment: Do you have an external speaker? If yes, is the sound issuing from it or from the inbuilt speaker?

Comment: you said, just installed win7. which was your os later and did you faced any such issues with that os?. does this sound comes only after stopping a player or chat or it happens randomly?.

Comment: What kind of Audio Software are you using? Does it happen with every music player? and When you say voice conversation you mean Skype ?

Answer (score 3):

Open Sound settings and then open Sound Tab. After this, disable the default sound effect for Close Program.

If it doesn't help, open the sounds settings, Under playback tab, you will find your speaker. Click on it and then disable your "Loudness Equalization". If it is already disabled then enable it

Comment: In addition to these steps it can also help to disable all sound enhancements in general. You might also want to disable "listen" just to be safe.